# Sinch iOS API Support CallKit Framework?

Tags: ios, sinch, callkit

In my application, I am using Sinch API for audio and Video call functionality. it's working fine.

But I want to implement UI for the Incoming audio call is like normal phone call UI (like WhatsApp audio call) when the application is not in foreground state (application is in "Background/Inactive/Terminated").

So I want's to know, is Sinch API support CallKit framework or not? if Not then is there any other way to implement this functionality with Sinch API?

Comment: We are working on it, it should be ready in a few weeks

Comment: @cjensen: - It will be much appreciated!Can you please provide tentative date for this?

Comment: Is Sinch working on Callkit Swift code? @cjensen
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sinch support CallKit. I used it in my iOS app. [link for news](https://www.sinch.com/company/december-2017-whats-new/)

for run application in Background/Inactive/Terminated state first you must upload APNS certificates, one for each type - Development, Production & VoIP Services of your app to Sinch server.

[image]

Comment: No, only drug and drop.

Comment: I am asking about adding callkit to sinch.

Comment: i am done with Swift-5 Code more details Contact me on email: ahmedshakeelpk@gmail.com